# My for loop is not iterating through all possible values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to store substrings of letters in 's' that are in alphabetical order in a list

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
string = ''
List = []
i = -1
for letter in s:

    if letter == s[0]:
        string += letter

    elif letter >= s[i]:
        string += letter

    elif letter < s[i]:
        List.append(string)
        string = letter

    i += 1
print(List)
```

My expected result:

> `['az', 'c', 'bo', 'bo', 'beggh', 'akl']`

And my actual Output:

> `['az', 'c', 'bo', 'bo']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your first `if` statement is incorrect. It should be `if i == -1:`. Because of this bug, you are ignoring the second `a` character in `s`.

Secondly, at the end of the string you don't add what's left of `string` into `List`.

As such, the following is what you want:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
string = ''
List = []
i = -1
for letter in s:
    if i == -1:
        string += letter

    elif letter >= s[i]:
        string += letter

    elif letter < s[i]:
        List.append(string)
        string = letter

    i += 1

List.append(string)
print(List)
```

An example is available [here](https://ideone.com/7NDICw).

Comment: I would also mention that `List` is bad practice for naming his variable, it does not shadow `list` type but I'd still mention it. Except for that, good insight!

Comment: That's a fair point. I'm sure [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would have a lot more to say on this code.

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate this

Comment: @Mukhtar Agboola if this solution answers your question then please accept it as answered, this may help someone who has a related issue in the future:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers